# How can I access methods attributes with Spring AOP (AspectJ-style)?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I need to intrecept some methods and their attributes by using annotations as point cuts, but how can I access those method attributes. I have following code that succesfully can run code before method is run, but I just don't know how I can access those attrbiutes.

```
package my.package;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

 @Pointcut(value="execution(public * *(..))")
 public void anyPublicMethod() {
 }

 @Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(myAnnotation )")
 public Object myAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, MyAnnotation myAnnotation)
    throws Throwable {

  // how can I access method attributes here ?
  System.out.println("hello aspect!");
  return pjp.proceed();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get them from the `ProceedingJoinPoint` object:

```
@Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(myAnnotation )")
public Object myAspect(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
    final MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable{

    // retrieve the methods parameter types (static):
    final Signature signature = pjp.getStaticPart().getSignature();
    if(signature instanceof MethodSignature){
        final MethodSignature ms = (MethodSignature) signature;
        final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = ms.getParameterTypes();
        for(final Class<?> pt : parameterTypes){
            System.out.println("Parameter type:" + pt);
        }
    }

    // retrieve the runtime method arguments (dynamic)
    for(final Object argument : pjp.getArgs()){
        System.out.println("Parameter value:" + argument);
    }

    return pjp.proceed();
}
```

Comment: Ok now Im getting it, but it returns odd parameters. org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper@8c666a
org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper@197d20c . My method is Spring controller with @RequestMapping and my own annotation. Why its giving me some Spring Security objects here when it should give HttpServletRequest object  as params?

Comment: Those are spring proxies around the original http request objects. See my updated answer: you can get both the defined parameter types (static analysis) and the actual runtime arguments (dynamic analysis)

Comment: How can I get static parameter values, in this case HttpServletRequest object ?

Comment: I showed you how to get the static type in my updated answer. But I don't think that's what you mean. Don't worry: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper *is* actually a HttpServletRequest implementation (see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.html) that delegates functionality to the original request underneath.

Answer (score 5):

`ProceedingJoinPoint` has `pjp.getArgs()`, which returns all the parameters of the method.

(but these are called parameters / arguments, not attributes)